# Deezer Android SDK - PLAYBACK_COMPLETED right after starting to play a track

Tags: android, media-player, deezer

I am currently having the following problem with the Deezer Android SDK (0.11.1):

1. I'm calling TrackPlayer#playTrack. The TrackPlayer runs through all the expected states (INITIALIZING -> READY -> WAITING_FOR_DATA -> PLAYING)
2. When the track ends the PLAYBACK_COMPLETED state is correctly being reported. I respond by calling TrackPlayer#playTrack with a new URI which again is being followed by all expected PlayerStates.
3. But after approximately 2 seconds onPlayerStateChange is being called again and reports a transition to the PLAYBACK_COMPLETED state even though the track just started playing.

### Log

Here's the log that shows the above thing happening:

```
02-16 17:51:47.089  22376-22376/com.test V/DeezerService﹕ onPlayerProgress: 219132
02-16 17:51:47.089  22376-22376/com.test V/DeezerService﹕ onPlayerProgress: 219132
02-16 17:51:47.099  22376-22376/com.test V/DeezerService﹕ onPlayerProgress: 219132
02-16 17:51:47.099  22376-22376/com.test V/DeezerService﹕ onPlayerProgress: 219132
02-16 17:51:47.269  22376-22376/com.test V/DeezerService﹕ onPlayerProgress: 219355
02-16 17:51:47.269  22376-22376/com.test D/DeezerService﹕ onPlayerStateChange: PLAYBACK_COMPLETED
02-16 17:51:47.319  22376-22376/com.test D/DeezerService﹕ pause called
02-16 17:51:47.329  22376-22376/com.test D/DeezerService﹕ prepare called: 65631310
02-16 17:51:47.749  22376-22376/com.test D/DeezerService﹕ onPlayerStateChange: STOPPED
02-16 17:51:47.749  22376-22376/com.test D/DeezerService﹕ onPlayerStateChange: INITIALIZING
02-16 17:51:47.749  22376-22376/com.test D/DeezerService﹕ onPlayerStateChange: READY
02-16 17:51:47.749  22376-22376/com.test D/DeezerService﹕ onPlayerStateChange: WAITING_FOR_DATA
02-16 17:51:47.829  22376-22376/com.test D/DeezerService﹕ onPlayerStateChange: PLAYING
02-16 17:51:50.109  22376-22376/com.test V/DeezerService﹕ onPlayerProgress: 2263
02-16 17:51:50.129  22376-22376/com.test V/DeezerService﹕ onPlayerProgress: 2263
02-16 17:51:50.129  22376-22376/com.test V/DeezerService﹕ onPlayerProgress: 2263
02-16 17:51:50.129  22376-22376/com.test V/DeezerService﹕ onPlayerProgress: 2285
02-16 17:51:50.129  22376-22376/com.test V/DeezerService﹕ onPlayerProgress: 2285
02-16 17:51:50.139  22376-22376/com.test V/DeezerService﹕ onPlayerProgress: 2285
02-16 17:51:50.139  22376-22376/com.test V/DeezerService﹕ onPlayerProgress: 2285
02-16 17:51:50.139  22376-22376/com.test V/DeezerService﹕ onPlayerProgress: 2285
02-16 17:51:50.139  22376-22376/com.test V/DeezerService﹕ onPlayerProgress: 2285
02-16 17:51:50.139  22376-22376/com.test V/DeezerService﹕ onPlayerProgress: 2285
02-16 17:51:50.139  22376-22376/com.test V/DeezerService﹕ onPlayerProgress: 2285
02-16 17:51:50.289  22376-22376/com.test V/DeezerService﹕ onPlayerProgress: 2438
02-16 17:51:50.339  22376-22376/com.test V/DeezerService﹕ onPlayerProgress: 145987
02-16 17:51:50.349  22376-22376/com.test D/DeezerService﹕ onPlayerStateChange: PLAYBACK_COMPLETED
02-16 17:51:50.499  22376-22376/com.test D/DeezerService﹕ pause called
02-16 17:51:50.499  22376-22376/com.test D/DeezerService﹕ prepare called: 84055801
02-16 17:51:50.739  22376-22376/com.test D/DeezerService﹕ onPlayerStateChange: STOPPED
02-16 17:51:50.739  22376-22376/com.test D/DeezerService﹕ onPlayerStateChange: INITIALIZING
02-16 17:51:50.739  22376-22376/com.test D/DeezerService﹕ onPlayerStateChange: READY
02-16 17:51:50.739  22376-22376/com.test D/DeezerService﹕ onPlayerStateChange: WAITING_FOR_DATA
02-16 17:51:50.989  22376-22376/com.test D/DeezerService﹕ onPlayerStateChange: PLAYING
02-16 17:51:53.309  22376-22376/com.test V/DeezerService﹕ onPlayerProgress: 2263
02-16 17:51:53.479  22376-22376/com.test V/DeezerService﹕ onPlayerProgress: 2438
02-16 17:51:53.479  22376-22376/com.test V/DeezerService﹕ onPlayerProgress: 2438
02-16 17:51:53.489  22376-22376/com.test V/DeezerService﹕ onPlayerProgress: 2438
02-16 17:51:53.489  22376-22376/com.test V/DeezerService﹕ onPlayerProgress: 2438
02-16 17:51:53.489  22376-22376/com.test V/DeezerService﹕ onPlayerProgress: 2438
02-16 17:51:53.829  22376-22376/com.test V/DeezerService﹕ onPlayerProgress: 2786
02-16 17:51:53.829  22376-22376/com.test V/DeezerService﹕ onPlayerProgress: 2786
02-16 17:51:53.829  22376-22376/com.test V/DeezerService﹕ onPlayerProgress: 2786
02-16 17:51:53.839  22376-22376/com.test V/DeezerService﹕ onPlayerProgress: 2786
02-16 17:51:53.839  22376-22376/com.test V/DeezerService﹕ onPlayerProgress: 2786
02-16 17:51:53.999  22376-22376/com.test V/DeezerService﹕ onPlayerProgress: 2960
02-16 17:51:53.999  22376-22376/com.test V/DeezerService﹕ onPlayerProgress: 2960
02-16 17:51:54.179  22376-22376/com.test V/DeezerService﹕ onPlayerProgress: 3134
02-16 17:51:54.209  22376-22376/com.test D/DeezerService﹕ pause called
02-16 17:51:54.259  22376-22376/com.test V/DeezerService﹕ onPlayerProgress: 3178
02-16 17:51:54.259  22376-22376/com.test D/DeezerService﹕ onPlayerStateChange: PAUSED
```

### Workaround

This problem can be avoided by releasing the TrackPlayer and creating a new one every time a new track should be played. Obviously this is merely a workaround though.